# pass explicit intent from ViewPagerAdapter to fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a viewpager with two tabs, and a fragment for each. How do i send an intent string extra to say FragmentMathematics()?  This isnt as straight forward as creating an intent with a putExtra and then calling strartActivity().

**Here is my simple class.**

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private String check;
private PagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout404);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Mathematics"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Physics"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    check = intent.getStringExtra("SELECTVALUE");


    if("Mathematics".equalsIgnoreCase(check)){
        selectPage(1);
    } else {
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    }

     tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

void selectPage(int pageIndex){
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setScrollPosition(pageIndex,0f,true);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageIndex);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Show your adapter class.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I forgot about the adapter class. Its been a year since i wrote it. I was able to pass the bundle there and send it with a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bundle to pass data to fragment.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "Your Value");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
FragmentMathematics fragobj = new FragmentMathematics();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

And In fragment OnCreate()

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    

}
```